# Comexception without error code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am automating of ppt creation. The SaveAs method is throwing an exception. The exception message is:

> Presentation (unknown member) : An error occurred while PowerPoint was
>   saving the file.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I can't locate the error code out of this. Can anybody help me in this?

Note: I am using Windows 7 - 64 bit

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Click the first link, you have to document the HRESULT.

Answer (score 0):

Before I give you some tips on getting that error code, here's something I found on Microsoft support website:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 <- might be a good read.  It may or may not be applicable to your situation.

To get the last error, you would use:
 `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx

Since you're trying to get the code, this may very well work:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getexceptioncode(v=vs.110).aspx

You might have to use PInvoke:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx

Here's an SO thread does a good job of explanining what needs to be done.  The example there might not have the same code as yours, but it provides a good reference point.  Unfortunately, I do not see enough of your code in your screenshot:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17918729/2006048