# C# unmanaged code call not working: AddConsoleAlias

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I have the following code which keeps returning FALSE with a value of 8 from the `GetLastError()` call.

8 apparently is `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`.

I of course have enough memory, but the process doesn't think so, can anyone enlighten me as to what could be going wrong?

The code below is all I have except for the Forms objects declarations of course, but I guess there is no need to see this as I have 2 text boxes and 1 button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AddConsoleAlias
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AddConsoleAlias(string Source, string Target, string ExeName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetLastError();

        private void btnAddAlias_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AddConsoleAlias(txbSource.Text, txbTarget.Text, "cmd.exe"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Problem occured - {0}", GetLastError()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps the values are wrong somehow. Try a simple example like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682057(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try using [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918266/winapi-getlasterror-vs-marshal-getlastwin32error/17918729#17918729) -- the error you are seeing might be wrong.

Comment: To add to what @dbc said: to avoid having to decode the output of `GetLastWin32Error()`, use `throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())`.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert - or just type `new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).ToString()` in the immediate window if you don't want to throw & catch the exception.

Comment: @dbc: right -- I'm so used to writing wrapper functions for unmanaged calls that I didn't even consider that.

Comment: Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString() also seems to return the value 8, so I don't know, maybe the values I enter are not accepted, but I have used simple string as well as paths. @Brian, what values did you test with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddConsoleAlias` defines console alias. You have Windows Forms application without opened console. Console should be allocated before `AddConsoleAlias` invoke. To do that you can use `AllocConsole` function.

C# binding for this function is:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", 
        EntryPoint = "AllocConsole",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int AllocConsole();
```

Your modified code will look like:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", 
        EntryPoint = "AllocConsole",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AddConsoleAlias(string Source, string Target, string ExeName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetLastError();

    private void btnAddAlias_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      AllocConsole();

      if (AddConsoleAlias(txbSource.Text, txbTarget.Text, "cmd.exe"))
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
      }
      else
      {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Problem occured - {0}", GetLastError()));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikita, you put me on the right track. AllocConsole() did not work as expected, a console did open but I could not interact with it. Instead I used AttachConsole() and made sure I already had a console running, this did the trick. C# binding is: [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);