# OpenProcess returns error code 6(ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)

Tags: c#, winapi, openprocess

I try to get a handle to a running process using the `OpenProcess` function. However, when checking the error code I get an error code of 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE).

Here is a reduced sample:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    class TestClass
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetLastError();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess,
               bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress,
              byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        static void Main() 
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Sample")[0];
            var processHandle = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, process.Id);    
            Console.WriteLine(GetLastError());

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(1095090201);

            WriteProcessMemory(
                (int)processHandle,
                0x21F3CAAC,
                buffer,
                buffer.Length, 
                ref bytesRead);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm not really sure why it does not work.
It just returns Error Code 6. Some suggestions?

I somehow have the feeling it is because of the program I'm accessing, but everything else is running just fine and does not return any other errors.

Comment: `6` is `INVALID_HANDLE`, `GetLastError()` is only valid if `OpenProcess()` fails, i.e when `processHandle == 0`  is that the case?  `SetLastError = true` should be added to the attribute, what type of process is `Sample`? - Is this your real code? as it stands it would not compile

Comment: @AlexK. Well first of all, yea processHandle returns 0. Sample is a standard .exe programm. And no it isn't my real code, because i just took a part out of it and tried to keep it small (It is originally a Windows Form Application)

Comment: Showing fake code that doesn't check for errors correctly is not cool. Please put that right and don't do it again. Until you do it's hard for us to believe anything that is written here. The magic constants are very helpful either. Are we really to go look them up to work out what access you specified. Your golden rule here is that you should make it as easy as possible for us to help you. The idea is that you do as much of the leg work as possible, and we only do the parts that you cannot.

Comment: @DirkVollmar The asker said, "it isn't my real code"

Comment: @DirkVollmar OK, well, if you think that the question has all that is needed to answer definitively, and that the question cannot be improved, that's fine. I don't agree.

Answer (score 1):

You need to improve your error checking. You need to check first whether the return code of `OpenProcess` is null before you request the last error. Note that the `DllImport` needs `SetLastError` to be set to true for this to correctly work and `GetLastError` [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17918729/40347).

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess,
       bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

processHandle = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, process.Id); 
if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Ideally, you'd create a managed exception from the native error code. This has the advantage that you can use standard .NET exception handling and that you get error code and textual description nicely wrapped up in an exception:

```
processHandle = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, process.Id); 
if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // calls Marhal.GetLastWin32Error and GetErrorMessage under the hood
    throw new Win32Exception();
}
```

And, of course, don't forget to call `CloseHandle` when you're done.

Comment: It's still printing 6 and at the second example it's returning the Handle is  invalid, but not why...

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid`

Comment: @DirkVollmar What were you expecting to happen when you threw that exception. Nothing else could be expected. Can you explain why `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` is returned? That is, after all, the question.

Comment: The first comment to this answer contradicts that hypothesis. This is the problem with the fake code. We cannot see the code that the asker is running. Perhaps it has handled the errors correctly, and OpenProcess really is serving up `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. Or perhaps the asker's code still gets the error handling wrong. This is what is wrong with the question. We end up trying to reason about something that we cannot see. We need to the asker to show the code that they are running, with correct error handling, and then we can move forward.