# C# read USB Hid UPS status

Tags: c#, usb, pinvoke, hid, ups

UPS is Soltec Apa-650 with "megatec battery driver".
Even being in the device manager battery area, it doesn't appear in the Win32_Battery.

Status is available with *Upsilon 2000* software (remaining, temperature, etc...).
But now I need to read these values from a C# program
First idea: After seeing the payload with Wireshark, I want to replay it with c#. Any Idea?

For example, I tried pinvoke

`deviceHandle = Kernel32.CreateFile(deviceInstancePath, 0, Constants.FileShareRead | Constants.FileShareWrite, IntPtr.Zero, Constants.OpenExisting, 0, 0);` 
=> The handle is ok

`var success = Kernel32.WriteFile( deviceInformation.WriteHandle, outputReportBuffer, outputReportBuffer.Length, ref numberOfBytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);`
=> The success returns false

Does anybody know where I can find the failing explanation?

Any help would be appreciated (*sorry for my English, I'm a french guy*)

**Edit**

Thank's to aja here is the answer about the failing explaination

```
Win32Exception a = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
Console.WriteLine(a.Message)
```

Comment: Calling Marshall. GetLastWin32Error might be worth trying - as explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918266/winapi-getlasterror-vs-marshal-getlastwin32error

Comment: Thank you very much aja. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: In my case I just listened to the TCP/UDP traffic but could not send commands to the UPS. `tcp.port == 2570 connect as a client and get data`,
`tcp.port == 8652 read the data from the sms server` and 
`udp.port == 11541 udp data`